# Is "échances" a valid word?

Tags: choix-de-mot, typographie

I was reading an article and came across the word "échances". Searching the dictionaries (Oxford Hachette and Wiktionary) did not yield any result. Google Translate suggested that this is a typo of the word "échéances". Searching Google for "échances" also turns up a lot of results. So is this a valid word?

Here is the sentence in the original article:

> D'où l'appel lancé aux électeurs avant les *échances* qui vont se multiplier cette année notamment aux Pays-Bas, en France, en Allemagne, pour, comme le souligne Pervenche Bérès "armer le bras de nos responsables élus et faire de l'Europe cette force de liberté, de solidarité, de responsabilité, dont on a tellement besoin à l'échelle planétaire".

Comment: [échéance](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9ch%C3%A9ance) is indeed a valid word, "échance" does not exist - a typo as you say.

Comment: Could you give an excerpt of the article giving enough context to imagine the meaning intended?

Comment: I added the original sentence

Comment: Looks like a tipo indeed. Also you aparently made another in the sentence starting with "Searching Google for "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's certainly a typo as **échances** is not a french word. The correct word would have been **échéances**.